# What for can be used FabricMySQLDriver, what changes if I connect without it?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I use the following code to connect to MySQL:

```
public class DriverFabric {
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smartcrm";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Driver driver = null;

    try {
        driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connected");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(connection!=null){
            connection.close();
        }
    }


}
}
```

And it connects ok. But it also connects OK if I comment this Fabric class:

```
/* 
try {
        driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
*/
```

In the more recent JDBC libraries it is not even included. So does it benifits some how to my code, or better connect MySQL directly without this Fabric class?

Comment: You shouldn't be registering drivers yourself, drivers do that themselves when they are loaded. Also according to http://insidemysql.com/tag/fabric/ Fabric support is still included in the latest drivers. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/connector-j-fabric-connect.html on how to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not register drivers yourself, drivers do that themselves when they are loaded. And since Java 6 (JDBC 4.0), drivers will be discovered and loaded automatically.

Also according to http://insidemysql.com/tag/fabric/ Fabric support is still included in the latest drivers. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/connector-j-fabric-connect.html on how to connect.

For example the driver is called `com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.Driver`, not `FabricMySQLDriver`, and the URL you need to connect to Fabric has the prefix `jdbc:mysql:fabric://`. As far as I can tell, your current code has always been connecting using the normal MySQL driver.